# Why is this SQL query for Java throwing an exception?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

I desperately need help with my uni task. The following query throws an exception when executing the main() of my Springboot project since apparently the query fails.

I tried to adapt the original findAllByKeyword() from the sample code to my project.
The difference is that in the sample project the supervisor has a foreign key "id_keyword"
and in my project the Professor does not have one.
Tbh I am not well familiar with the syntax of the given query and tried to adapt it as best as I could.

You can find the exact error msg at the bottom of this post.

With this method I want to find all corresponding Professors for a given Stichpunkt (means keyword in german)

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT p FROM Professor p " +
        "WHERE p.id_professor = professor_hat_stichpunkt.id_professor " +
        "AND professor_hat_stichpunkt.id_stichpunkt = stichpunkt.id_stichpunkt " +
        "AND stichpunkt.id_stichpunkt = :stichpunkt" +
        "ORDER BY p.nachname")
List<Professor> findAllByKeyword(@Param("stichpunkt") Stichpunkt stichpunkt);
```

[DB image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFk15.png)

The Professor Class is as follows:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Table(name = "professor")
public class Professor {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_professor", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "vorname", nullable = false)
    private String vorname;


    @Column(name = "nachname", nullable = false)
    private String nachname;


    @Column(name = "titel", nullable = false)
    private String titel;

    @Column(name = "mailadresse", nullable = false)
    private String mailadresse;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Stichpunkt.class, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_stichpunkt", referencedColumnName = "id_stichpunkt", nullable = false)
    private Stichpunkt stichpunkt;



    public void setStichpunkt(Stichpunkt stichpunkt) {
        this.stichpunkt = stichpunkt;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Professor that = (Professor) o;
        return Objects.equals(getId(), that.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getId());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return nachname; // + " (" + (id == null ? "<null>" : id) + ')';
    }


    public String getVorname() {
        return vorname;
    }

    public String getNachname() {
        return nachname;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

}
```

---

The Stichpunkt class is as follows:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Objects;


@Entity

@Table(name = "stichpunkt")
public class Stichpunkt {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_stichpunkt", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "titel", nullable = false)
    private String titel;

    @Column(name = "beschreibung", nullable = false)
    private String beschreibung;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitel() {
        return titel;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return titel + " (" + (id == null ? "<null>" : id) + ')';
    }
}
```

---

ProfessorHatStichpunkt class:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Table(name = "professor_hat_stichpunkt")
public class ProfessorHatStichpunkt {
    @EmbeddedId
    private Id id;

    public ProfessorHatStichpunkt() {
    }

    public ProfessorHatStichpunkt(Professor professor, Stichpunkt stichpunkt) {
        this.id = new Id(professor, stichpunkt);
    }

    public Id getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Id id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        ProfessorHatStichpunkt that = (ProfessorHatStichpunkt) o;
        return Objects.equals(getId(), that.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getId());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SupervisorHasKeyword{id=" + (id == null ? "<null>" : id) + '}';
    }

    @Embeddable
    public static class Id implements Serializable {
        @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Professor.class, optional = false)
        @JoinColumn(name = "id_professor", referencedColumnName = "id_professor", nullable = false)
        private Professor professor;

        @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Stichpunkt.class, optional = false)
        @JoinColumn(name = "id_stichpunkt", referencedColumnName = "id_stichpunkt", nullable = false)
        private Stichpunkt stichpunkt;

        public Id() {
        }

        public Id(Professor professor, Stichpunkt stichpunkt) {
            this.professor = professor;
            this.stichpunkt = stichpunkt;
        }

        public Professor getProfessor() {
            return professor;
        }

        public void setProfessor(Professor professor) {
            this.professor = professor;
        }

        public Stichpunkt getStichpunkt() {
            return stichpunkt;
        }

        public void setStichpunkt(Stichpunkt stichpunkt) {
            this.stichpunkt = stichpunkt;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
            Id id = (Id) o;
            return Objects.equals(getProfessor(), id.getProfessor()) && Objects.equals(getStichpunkt(), id.getStichpunkt());
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(getProfessor(), getStichpunkt());
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("%s has %s", professor, stichpunkt);
        }
    }
}
```

---

The thing is this builds on a given sample project which works and I just adapted the code.
The working sample code is the following:

```
public interface SupervisorRepository extends JpaRepository<Supervisor, Integer> {
    @Query("SELECT DISTINCT s FROM Supervisor s " +
            "INNER JOIN SupervisorHasKeyword shk ON shk.id.supervisor = s " +
            "WHERE s.keyword = :keyword " +
            "OR shk.id.keyword = :keyword " +
            "ORDER BY s.name")
    List<Supervisor> findAllByKeyword(@Param("keyword")Keyword keyword);
}
```

[sample project DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hmZw.png)

The Supervisor class is as follows:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Table(name = "supervisor")
public class Supervisor {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_supervisor", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Keyword.class, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_keyword", referencedColumnName = "id_keyword", nullable = false)
    private Keyword keyword;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Keyword getKeyword() {
        return keyword;
    }

    public void setKeyword(Keyword keyword) {
        this.keyword = keyword;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Supervisor that = (Supervisor) o;
        return Objects.equals(getId(), that.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getId());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + " (" + (id == null ? "<null>" : id) + ')';
    }
}
```

---

Keyword class:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Table(name = "keyword")
public class Keyword {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_keyword", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "text", nullable = false)
    private String text;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Keyword keyword = (Keyword) o;
        return Objects.equals(getId(), keyword.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getId());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return  text + " (" + (id == null ? "<null>" : id) + ')';
    }
}
```

---

SupervisorHasKeyword class:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Table(name = "supervisor_has_keyword")
public class SupervisorHasKeyword {
    @EmbeddedId
    private Id id;

    public SupervisorHasKeyword() {
    }

    public SupervisorHasKeyword(Supervisor supervisor, Keyword keyword) {
        this.id = new Id(supervisor, keyword);
    }

    public Id getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Id id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        SupervisorHasKeyword that = (SupervisorHasKeyword) o;
        return Objects.equals(getId(), that.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getId());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SupervisorHasKeyword{id=" + (id == null ? "<null>" : id) + '}';
    }

    @Embeddable
    public static class Id implements Serializable {
        @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Supervisor.class, optional = false)
        @JoinColumn(name = "id_supervisor", referencedColumnName = "id_supervisor", nullable = false)
        private Supervisor supervisor;

        @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Keyword.class, optional = false)
        @JoinColumn(name = "id_keyword", referencedColumnName = "id_keyword", nullable = false)
        private Keyword keyword;

        public Id() {
        }

        public Id(Supervisor supervisor, Keyword keyword) {
            this.supervisor = supervisor;
            this.keyword = keyword;
        }

        public Supervisor getSupervisor() {
            return supervisor;
        }

        public void setSupervisor(Supervisor supervisor) {
            this.supervisor = supervisor;
        }

        public Keyword getKeyword() {
            return keyword;
        }

        public void setKeyword(Keyword keyword) {
            this.keyword = keyword;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
            Id id = (Id) o;
            return Objects.equals(getSupervisor(), id.getSupervisor()) && Objects.equals(getKeyword(), id.getKeyword());
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(getSupervisor(), getKeyword());
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("%s has %s", supervisor,  keyword);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
Error:


Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'professorService' defined in file [C:\Users\...\camunda\database\service\ProfessorService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'professorRepository' defined in de.ostfalia.bips.ws22.camunda.database.repository.ProfessorRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List de.ostfalia.bips.ws22.camunda.database.repository.ProfessorRepository.findAllByKeyword(de.ostfalia.bips.ws22.camunda.database.domain.Stichpunkt); Reason: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List de.ostfalia.bips.ws22.camunda.database.repository.ProfessorRepository.findAllByKeyword(de.ostfalia.bips.ws22.camunda.database.domain.Stichpunkt)!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List de.ostfalia.bips.ws22.camunda.database.repository.ProfessorRepository.findAllByKeyword(de.ostfalia.bips.ws22.camunda.database.domain.Stichpunkt)!
```

Comment: So many problems here, but mainly:

1. You didn't define relations between you JPA entities (and may be `ProfessorHatStichpunkt` will be eliminated if you will do so)

2. Your query for `findAllByKeyword` is wrong, there is no `JOIN` of related entities.

Answer (score 0):

> since apparently the query fails

The query itself is not failing, it hasn't been executed at the point you get the exception. The exception is telling you that professorRepository can't be instantiated because you're referencing a bean in it's constructor that either doesn't exist, or is not a managed bean, but take a look at the first parameter in your constructor ("Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;")